# Windows detects SD card but can't read it's contents

Tags: windows, sd-card

All of a sudden my Windows XP PC can't read what is on SD cards and some USB sticks.

Even though the drive is detected, it shows it empty.

I don't have that problem reading the same cards on my iMac and everything was working fine before.

Is there anything I can do to resolve this problem?

Comment: Staff? We are not staff?

Comment: Can you try a different windows machine?

Comment: Might the problem be that the cards which don't work are formatted using a "Mac Only" Filesystem (HFS), rather then FAT?

Comment: i did format all the cards to FAT 32, and i just did try the card and a usb stick on a windows laptop and the same cards worked fine (following advise of ForeverWintr)

Comment: When you say "it shows it empty", what is the "it"? And by "empty", do you mean no filesystems? Or filesystems with no files? Or what?

Comment: David i am talking about SD cards and USB stick, empty = no files on the SD card.